# p:ribbon overrides spinner's button background

Tags: css, primefaces

The new [`<p:ribbon>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/ribbon.xhtml) component in PrimeFaces 5.1 overrides the `background` attribute of spinner component buttons using the class `.ui-ribbon` `.ui-button` (ribbon.css), which makes the spinner look like this:

[image]

```css
.ui-ribbon .ui-button {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   box-shadow: none;
   color: #333;
}
```

When background rule is disabled in the browser, the spinner looks perfect

[image]

How can I write my CSS to make it ignore the background definition on `.ui-ribbon` `.ui-button`, so it can keep using the theme background definition?

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following:

```
.ui-spinner.ui.ribbon .ui-button {
  background: none!important;
}
```

**OR** if .ui-spinner is a container element:

```
.ui-spinner .ui-ribbon .ui-button {
  background: none !important;
}
```

Basically, what this is saying is that when a `spinner` is also a `ribbon`, don't show a background on `button` even if it's already defined.

In the second case, it's saying when `button` is a child of `ribbon` which is also a child of `spinner`, then don't show a background even if it's already defined.

---

## Edit:

Ah, so you're worried about overriding a previously applied background.  Makes much more sense.  In that case, change the above CSS to this:

```
.ui-spinner.ui.ribbon .ui-button {
  background: inherit!important;
}
```

**OR** if .ui-spinner is a container element:

```
.ui-spinner .ui-ribbon .ui-button {
  background: inherit!important;
}
```

Comment: Mmmm it didnt work, from what i get, i cannot set the background to none because the blue color that I want is given by the background in other other selector. When i disable the first background, the second brings back the blue color [selectors](http://i.imgur.com/gl5PgaG.png).